# Alternative to multiple SVG files on website

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a website and I call like 50 different SVG images, for example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" width="50" height="50" data="img/icons/image1.svg">
  Image1
</object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" width="50" height="50" data="img/icons/image2.svg">
  Image2
</object>
```

This is obviously not the best way to do this since it increases the number of http requests and slows down the site. What is the best way. to combine all these images into one file and call them like that?

Comment: I'd say yes. Generate a sprite with the individual SVG's and autogenerate a css file that can can be used for each icon. That is until http2.0 :)

Comment: https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/

Comment: For icons I would recommend creating a font.

Comment: Yeah, that's what icon moon does. Please remove your downvote.